# highstock attaching panning feature to mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

im very new to highstocks im trying to see if I can bypass ie8 notworking with the liveRedraw feature by utilizing the panning feature which does work in ie8. I basically want to attach the panning function to the mousedown event. if someone could assist or point me in the right direction that would be great.     http://jsfiddle.net/danpbrough/w1psjgu3/4/

```
            Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', drag);
        Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', drop);
```

ive added the event listeners above but am having trouble understanding the highcharts.js file to see where id add in the panning portion.

liveRedraw is turned to false to mimic ie8

Comment: You have errors. `normalizeMouseEvent` is not defined. There are `clientX`, `offsetX`, `pageX` and `screenX` but there is no `chartX` on `e`. What are you trying to do with the handlers? And there is no element with the id of `report` for using `document.getElementById('report')`!

Comment: sorry I meant to take all of that out. is there a way to trigger the panning function to happen when I click the scrollbar to get past the ie8 scrollbar not being able to use liveredraw?

Comment: sorry, I don't know about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much simpler way to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/w1psjgu3/7/

In callback just set `liveRedraw` to true, and will work:

```
function (chart) {
    chart.scroller.scrollbarOptions.liveRedraw = true;
}
```

However, IE8 has very poor performance and that's probably the reason for disabled `liveRedraw` for that browser (in the fact IE6/7/8 are the same case).

Comment: its going to take me a bit to test this so im going to mark this as the answer so you get the credit. at the very least you still pointed me in the direction I need. thanks so much.